# Is it possible to run Windows Server on Apple Xserve hardware?

Tags: windows-server-2008, apple, xserve, bootcamp

[Apple's Boot Camp](http://www.apple.com/macosx/features/bootcamp.html) allows you to run a Windows client OS on Apple hardware.  Has anyone had success in running a Windows Server OS natively on [Apple's Xserve](http://www.apple.com/xserve/) hardware?

Does anyone know if Boot Camp updates coming in Snow Leopard will support this?

Comment: I'm curious why you would even want to.  For the price of a base model Xserve, you could buy 2 Dell PowerEdge R200 boxes with almost identical specs.  Buy an Xserve if you want to run OSX Server.  Otherwise, save your money and buy a PC server that was designed to run Windows or Linux.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Boot Camp is not supported on Xserves:
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3307

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run windows on on xserve the recommended solution as far as I am aware is to run Parallels or VMWare and run a virtual windows server inside OS X server.

Answer (score 2):

Parallels now has a product that allows you to create a virtual Windows 2008 or 2003 server on your Xserve.

http://www.parallels.com/products/server/mac/